# Changing style for individual item in ListBox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox

I saw some examples for changing colors and brushes for selected item in a ListBox

I was wondering if there is a way to change visual properties of an item in a list box based on events in our code

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Name="spSceneThumb" Width="110">
          <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFfcfcfc" BorderBrush="#aaaaff" >
               <StackPanel></StackPanel>
          </Border>
      </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Let say I want to change border color of 5th item based on some event

I tried IValueConverter But changes to property wont effect border color

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a custom `RoutedEvent` that you could listen to with an `EventTrigger`. You can find out how to declare a custom `RoutedEvent` in the [How to: Create a Custom Routed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. Once created, you can reference your custom event using the class name before the event name and not forgetting the XAML Namespace Prefix that you define for the namespace where it was declared. Something like this:

```
RoutedEvent="YourNamespacePrefix:YourClassName.YourEventName"
```

However, changing discrete values like `Brush`es is not so simple using an `EventTrigger`. You'll have to use a `Storyboard` with a `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` element. You could try something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Something">
    <StackPanel Name="spSceneThumb" Width="110">
        <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFCFCFC">
            <StackPanel>
                ...
            </StackPanel>
            <Border.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EventBrush" Color="Red" />
            </Border.Resources>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFAAAAFF" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Prefix:YourClassName.YourEventName">
                            <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" 
                                                Value="{StaticResource EventBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```